# Polymorphism at runtime

Tags: c#

I am working on a webapi application with some basic inheritance and polymorphism aspects to a few of the data models.  One endpoint in particular is expected to receive and operate on any derived type of an abstract class.  With the aid of some JsonCreationConverter code, I can step into my code and see the proper derived type has been selected for my payload.

Things break however, when I then attempt to call a method with overrides for the specific derived types.  The compiler complains that it cannot convert from the abstract type to one of the derived types.

My guess is that this sort of polymorphism isn't allowed at runtime, or that I need to set things up differently to make it happen.

Here's a fiddle that describes the basic behavior I'm seeing [ https://dotnetfiddle.net/9BkSP8 ].  Of particular concern is the `webApiControllerAction2` method which has the code I'm hoping for.

While `webApiControllerAction1` is technically functional, it is not able to remain agnostic about `Shape`s derived types, and that's the bit I'm hoping to find an answer to.

### Edit

Hmm.. my fiddle link isn't showing the most recent version of this that I programmed.  I'll have to figure that out... ok... its now showing the correct version, how odd..

Comment: `My guess is that this sort of polymorphism isn't allowed at runtime` What you're describing *isn't polymorphism*.  And of course the reason it doesn't work is precisely because it isn't polymorphic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Took your fiddle and roughed-in the missing polymorphism](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OMzwSM):

```
using System;

public abstract class Shape {
    public string shapeType {get; set;}
    public abstract double Area { get; }
}

public class Circle : Shape
{
    public int radius {get; set;}
    public override double Area { get { return 3.1415 * radius * radius;} }
}

public class Square : Shape
{
    public int length {get; set;}
    public override double Area { get { return length * length;} }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World {0}" , "foo");
        var circle = new Circle() {shapeType= "Circle", radius = 5};
        var square = new Square() {shapeType= "Square",length = 5};

        webApiControllerAction(circle);
        webApiControllerAction(square);
    }

    public static void webApiControllerAction(Shape shape)
    {
        // just call the appropriate printArea for the derived type
        printArea(shape);
    }

    public static void printArea(Shape s) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} area = {1}", s.GetType().Name ,s.Area.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I would add a constructor to **Circle** and **Square** that sets the base class ShapeType to **nameof(Circle)** or **nameof(Square)**

Comment: @PaulBaxter "roughed-in". :-) Your idea to use nameof would be part of improvement, yep, as would just eliminate ShapeType altogether.

Comment: Thanks, but this misses what I'm trying to accomplish.  I can't (or don't wish to) add these methods to the derived shapes.  I just wish to use the fact that the items are a particular derived class to call the correct implimentation.  Basically, I want to avoid using the traffic-cop from the controllerAction.  I *completely understand* what you all are saying about how what I'm doing isn't really polymorphism, but instead, I wonder if there isn't some way to still take advantage of this idea.

Comment: @reidLinden Using the fact that the items are ... to call the correct implementation is exactly how the compiler gives us polymorphism. So far the code in your question just seems to highlight that the objects don't do anything useful with their ancestry. Looking forward to the updated fiddle to see what you are really hoping to accomplish.

Comment: well, I'm trying to keep things as simple as possible for the fiddle, but the gist of matters is that I have an API endpoint that should take some structured payment methods.  Sometimes, the endpoint will get an echeck, sometimes a ccard, and other times something else. The json converter correctly identifies when we have a paymentmethod_card type (or echeck) and then I'd like to pass this object off to a card specific processing method that lives in a different module of the application.  I am wanting to keep the data model POCO because it will be reused for other parts of the app.

Comment: having a `process(card object)` method and a `process(check object)` seems like a reasonable way to structure this, while keeping the methods out of my data model.

Comment: @reidLinden Perhaps the idea of data xfer can be separated from the idea of biz objects. So you can keep the classes you showed us as data xfer objects, then have biz objects that have a data xfer object instance inside and also implement the Area method. As it stands, it's anti-OO. Which is fine, but begs the question why an OO language?

Comment: I had considered the possibility of separating them as you say.  Perhaps I will.  I was actually trying to be OO, but just got it wrong.  Took a wrong turn at Albuquerque, if you will.  Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Ended up deciding to do as we discussed,   Thanks much for the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

That is not polymorphism. Here is an example of that using a method named `PrintArea`.

The result is that the behavior of the method varies depending on the implementer BUT the caller does not have to know the concrete type of the instance being utilized. In this case there is a list of shapes and the caller can call `PrintArea` but is unaware of how that method is implemented and of the type that implements the method.

[From Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science))

> In programming languages and type theory, polymorphism (from Greek πολύς, polys, "many, much" and morphē, "form, shape") is the **provision of a single interface to entities of different types.**

```
using System;

namespace TestCode
{
    public abstract class Shape
    {
        public abstract void PrintArea();
    }

    public class Circle : Shape
    {
        public override void PrintArea()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("πr2");
        }
    }

    public class Square : Shape
    {
        public override void PrintArea()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("l*w");
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start");
            var lst = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Shape>();
            lst.Add(new Circle());
            lst.Add(new Square());


            ShowFormula(lst);
        }

        public static void ShowFormula(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Shape> shapes){
            foreach (var shape in shapes)
              shape.PrintArea();
        }
    }
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Tu8Ras)

Comment: totally agree.  but for reasons described elsewhere, I have chosen to keep  my data objects clear of this process code.. Thanks, though